# Small bug with my contact form validation. Email validation is getting tangled with the rest of my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I've written some validation code for my contact form. While executing, the code will highlight an invalid input and display the (error) label.

While the validation is working correctly, the email input is incorrectly showing the label. Code below:

```js
 $(".cform").on("submit" , function(e){

   var hasError = false;

    $(".inputValidation").each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      var $label = $("label[for='"+$(this).attr("id")+"']");
      var validateEmail = function(elementValue){
          var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
    return emailPattern.test(elementValue);
      }
      var value = $('#email').val();
      var valid = validateEmail(value);

      if($this.val() == ""){
        hasError = true;
        $this.addClass("inputError");
        $label.addClass("label_error");
        e.preventDefault();
      }if(!valid){
        $("#email").addClass("inputError");
        $label.addClass("label_error");
        e.preventDefault();
      }if($this.val() != ""){
       $this.removeClass("inputError");
       $label.removeClass("label_error");
      }else{
       return true;
     }

    });
 });
```

```css
.cform {
  width: 50%;
}

.cform .inputError {
 background-color: #ffffff;
  outline: 2.5px solid #900f0f;
  color: black;
}

.input_label {
 display: none;
}

.label_error {
 display: block;
 color: #900f0f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="cform" action="" method="post">
     <label class="input_label" for="name">ERROR</label>
         <input type="text" id="name" class="inputValidation shad" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name...">
     <label class="input_label" for="email">ERROR</label>
         <input type="text" id="email" class="inputValidation shad" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email...">
     <label class="input_label" for="phone">ERROR</label>
         <input type="text" id="phone" class="inputValidation shad" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Contact Number...">
     <label class="input_label" for="message">ERROR</label>
         <textarea name="message" id="message" class="inputValidation shad" placeholder="Type your message here..."></textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="" name="sumbit" value="send">
      </form>
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/e71g5fgn/)

Comment: Can you give an example of a set of inputs that fails to meet your expectations? Testing it here, I only see the email error when I *don't* enter an email that's valid according to your regex (which is going to fail on many non-US domains, addresses with `+` in the username, etc. but that's a different topic).

Answer (score 0):

so the issue it seems was that you were adding the error label class correctly when the email was invalid but there was an if statement at the bottom that only checked for the val()!="" which means if the email had something in but was not a valid email it still had the label removed.

The easiest solution is to seperate the if statements.

```
$(".cform").on("submit" , function(e){

var hasError = false;

$(".inputValidation").each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var $label = $("label[for='"+$(this).attr("id")+"']");
  var validateEmail = function(elementValue){
    var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
    return emailPattern.test(elementValue);
  }
  var value = $('#email').val();
  var valid = validateEmail(value);

  if($this.val() == ""){
    hasError = true;
    $this.addClass("inputError");
    $label.addClass("label_error");
    e.preventDefault();
  }else{
    $this.removeClass("inputError");
    $label.removeClass("label_error");
  }

  if(!valid){
    $("#email").addClass("inputError");
    $label.addClass("label_error");
    e.preventDefault();
  }else{
   $this.removeClass("inputError");
   $label.removeClass("label_error");
 }

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Validations were not in proper sequence. Error which was generated by email field, got overridden by non null validation.

```js
 $(".cform").on("submit" , function(e){

   var hasError = false;

    $(".inputValidation").each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      var $label = $("label[for='"+$(this).attr("id")+"']");
      var validateEmail = function(elementValue){
          var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
    return emailPattern.test(elementValue);
      }
      var value = $('#email').val();
      var valid = validateEmail(value);
     //validation for mandatory start
      if($this.val() == ""){
        hasError = true;
        $this.addClass("inputError");
        $label.addClass("label_error");
        e.preventDefault();
      } else{
       $this.removeClass("inputError");
       $label.removeClass("label_error");
        return true;
      }
      //validation for mandatory end

      //validation for email start
      if(!valid){
        $("#email").addClass("inputError");
        $label.addClass("label_error");
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      else{
       $this.removeClass("inputError");
       $label.removeClass("label_error");
      }
     //validation for email end
      
    });
 });
```